# Exception uploading attachments using webchat

Tags: c#, botframework

We are having a problem uploading attachments to the Bot when using the webchat channel.
After an attachment is uploaded we get “Sorry, my bot code is having an issue” and in our logs we see the following exception:

Post received exception: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorHandling.d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)…

This is the code we are using to get the attachment content:

```
    private async Task StoreUserAttachments(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IEnumerable<Attachment>> attachments)
    {
        try
        {
            m_userAttachments = new List<UserAttachment>();
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            foreach (var attachment in await attachments)
            {
                PrivateTracer.Tracer.TraceInformation($"Got user attahcment with content type {attachment.ContentType} and name {attachment.Name}");
                var attachmentBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);
                m_userAttachments.Add(new UserAttachment {Filename = attachment.Name, ContentsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(attachmentBytes)});
            }
            await PromptNextQuestion(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var message = $"Got exception {exception}";
            PrivateTracer.Tracer.TraceError(message);
            context.Done(message);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that calls this function

```
PromptDialog.Attachment(context, StoreUserAttachments, "Please upload your files now.");
```

The exception is not caught by this try-catch, and it is only thrown from the webchat and not in the Bot emulator which makes it harder to debug.

Any ideas what is causing that?

---

edit

We narrowed down the problem:

1. The bad request exception only happens when we save the attachment to a field (m_userAttachments)
2. When we pass the attachments to the next method instead of saving them in a field we got the following exception:

   Post received exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSucces
   ...

Comment: I'm not sure how you end up with a IAwaitable<IEnumerable<Attachment>>, attachments usually arrives as part of the message. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I added the code that calls this function to the question

Comment: Right, you are using PromptAttachment, that makes sense. I think you should start isolating the problem, like commenting all the code and start with jus doing the await of the attachments. Then I would make sure the PromptNextQuestion is working fine

Comment: The interesting thing is, it works on the Emulator but not on the WebChat. Sounds like a bug in the Bot Framework. Also no place I put the try catch caught the exception...

Comment: I posted an update, we narrowed down the problem with your advice.

Comment: Mmm... Strange. Is the UserAttachment class serializable? Does it has the attribute?